# Screen dim events in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any methods to catch screen dim in android?

This code will work ?

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                            boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no broadcast event sent when screen brightness changes. Also with most phones now employing auto-brightness, at any moment, screen brightness will change based on the algorithm and content displayed on the screen. You can only check when the Screen goes off or comes back on.